# Detect month according to date selected?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have two label in webform Label1 and Label2

Label1 displays the date as 1-Apr-2011

I want to display month as April in Label2 if date in label1 is in between 1 to 30 Apr 2011.

I want to display month as May in Label2 if date in label1 is in between 1 to 30 May 2011.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the text in `Label1` into a `DateTime` object and get the `Month` property from that. Because this property is an `int` you can then use an enum for the translation to a month.

```
Public Enum MonthsInYear
  January = 1
  February = 2
  //...
End Enum

Dim month As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(Label1.Text)
Label2.Text = Enum.GetName(typeof(MonthsInYear), month)
```

See the [MSDN page on parse-method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326715%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C# you can try this:

Label2.Text = DateTime.Parse(lable1.text).ToString("M")

Answer (score 0):

To get current month name in VB.net

```
Today.ToString("MMMM")
```

and in C#.net

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM");
```